# Swift package manager (spm) protocols, are not recognised in the project

Tags: swift, protocols, swift-package-manager

I just converted a git repository to Swift Package Manager (spm), all good, it compiles and I can import it in the project.

What is not good is that the project doesn't compile, is not seeing the `protocol`. My lib is a single generic class and i'm supposed to create an enum that implements the protocol then use the enum as a generic of the class.

```
enum LocalPreferences: String, RCPreferencesProtocol {
```

**I get:** Use of undeclared type `RCPreferencesProtocol`

Then I get further errors when trying to use the enum but i think this are only because the enum had an error:

```
private let localPreferences = RCPreferences<LocalPreferences>()
```

**I get:** Cannot specialize a non-generic definition

Anybody had this problem and fixed it?

Here is reference to [the library](https://github.com/ralcr/RCPreferences) is the lib for reference.

Answer (score 2):

I made a stupid mistake, didn't declared the protocol and class public in the package. Strange though that the unit tests of the package passed instead giving the same error.

Comment: Does `@testable import` ignores `public` or something?